# Jenkins: The config profile (user_profile) could not be found Error: Cannot perform an interactive login from a non TTY device

Tags: docker, jenkins, aws-cli

I'm getting the error when executing the build with Jenkins:
**The config profile (user_profile) could not be found

Error: Cannot perform an interactive login from a non TTY device**

[image: console jenkins]

But from the command line it works, does anyone have any idea what it could be? Any credentials, access level or something like that?

[image: command line]

Comment: `The config profile (user_profile) could not be found`. Is that profile configured in your `/home/jenkins/.aws/config` file ? It seems not and it looks like your are testing with a different profile in your shell.

Comment: Yes, the name "user_profile" is fictitious, however, the user I am testing is at: /home/jenkins/.aws/config

Comment: Well then your pipeline is not reading that file, very probably because your are using sudo and that it is looking at `/root/.aws/config`

Comment: I managed to solve by installing two plugins: https://plugins.jenkins.io/docker-build-publish/ and https://plugins.jenkins.io/amazon-ecr/

Answer (score 0):

configure aws profile in jenkins user and after that verify permission to /var/lib/jenkins/credentials file.
it should be accessible by jenkins user.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CuXJk.png)